# In Clause With Subquery In Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle10g

I have two tables say table1 and table2 with below details

```
create table test1(id number, name varchar2(20)); 
insert into test1 values(11,'micro'); 
insert into test1 values(22,'soft'); 


create table test2(id number, name varchar2(20)); 
insert into test2 values(77,'micro,soft');
```

1) if I use below query I am getting no rows selectd

```
select * from test1 t1 where t1.name in ( select ''''||replace(t2.name,',',''',''')||''''  from test2;
```

2) if I fire subquery alone output I am getting is : `'micro','soft'`

```
select ''''||replace(t2.name,',',''',''')||''''  from test2;
```

but if I fire query(1) I need the result

```
id   name
------------
11 micro
22 soft
```

can some one please help me to get the same result with query (1).

Comment: Than you So much to every one, i got the solution with your suggestions

Answer (score 3):

You have a very strange data layout and should probably change it.

You can do what you want with a `join` or with a correlated subquery using `like`:

```
select *
from test1 t1
where exists (select 1
              from test2 t2
              where ','||t2.name||',' like '%,'||t1.name||',%'
             );
```

You version doesn't work because the expression:

```
where x in ('a,b,c')
```

tests where `x` is equal to the string value `'a,b,c'`, not whether it is equal to one of the three values.

Answer (score 1):

Use [REGEXP_SUBSTR](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions131.htm) function to get this done.

```
SELECT * 
FROM   test1 t1 
WHERE  t1.NAME IN(SELECT regexp_substr(t2.NAME, '[^,]+', 1, ROWNUM) 
                  FROM   test2 t2
                  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LENGTH (regexp_replace (t2.NAME, '[^,]+'))  + 1
                  );
```